# How do I get new HTML files to execute in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently started learning WebDev using Colt Steele Udemy course. I've created few HTML files and whenever I try to execute any of them only the first created .html file opens in Chrome. How do I get the other files to open in the browser. Eg: If I create 3 files i.e a.html, b.html & c.html only a.html opens in Chrome even if b/c is open in the editor. This happens with both debugging or run without debugging. My VS Code version is 1.65.2. Please advice.

The launch.json code is:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Open a.html",
      "file": "e:\\\\Colt Steele\\HTML the essentials\\a.html"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launch configuration you're showing is telling VSCode what to do when running the project.  You can change the launch configuration to open a different file by default:

```
{
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Open b.html",
  "file": "e:\\\\Colt Steele\\HTML the essentials\\b.html"
}
```

Or perhaps add multiple launch configurations, which you can select when debugging/running:

```
{
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Open a.html",
  "file": "e:\\\\Colt Steele\\HTML the essentials\\a.html"
},
{
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Open b.html",
  "file": "e:\\\\Colt Steele\\HTML the essentials\\b.html"
}
```

In general any given "application" would have a single default page as the entry point, and from there you can navigate through the application to use the other pages.  So you might have a single `index.html` as the launch file, and in whatever you're building there would be links to other files as needed for the application.

But if what you're building for whatever reason truly has different "entry points" then you can just set up your build configurations based on that and select which configuration to use when running the application.

---

*Alternatively* (and I haven't tested this), you *should* be able to tell it to launch "the current file" by using a variable called `file` in the launch config:

```
{
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Open Current File",
  "program": "${file}"
}
```

Comment: But isn't this supposed to happen without changing the file name every single time? How do I set the config such that launch.json need not be edited at all ?

Comment: @SriniShankar: I wasn't aware there was such functionality, but a little research found something.  I've updated the answer.  It's still somewhat uncommon to have multiple entry points or to not just "navigate the application" upon running it, but this approach could work.